# Azure Mobile Services Unable to retrieve [ComplexType] from .net backend

Tags: json, mobile, service, complextype

With the current Azure Mobile Services on a .NET Backend there seems to be an issue when you use a [ComplexType] property on a EntityData object.

for example:

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool Complete { get; set; }

    public ExampleComplexType Example { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class ExampleComplexType
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}
```

use that with the sample TodoItemController and the database gets created just fine, and data can be inserted/updated/etc. However the JSON returned from GetAllTodoItems() refuses to return the Example.

Any thoughts?